# Using Auth::user()->user() in Laravel 5.8 or later

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upgrade a Laravel project from Laravel 5.1 to 5.8. I noticed that instead of `Auth::user()`, `Auth::user()->user()` has been used in the project, and in Laravel 5.8 I get a null exception in some cases because `Auth::user` is null. Shall I replace all instances of `Auth::user()->user()` with `Auth::user()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use this-

```
Auth::user();
```

Or this-

```
auth()->user();
```

Please make sure that you have no method/relation with name **user()** in your user model which may be the reason you have **user()->user()** like syntax. If that's not the case then feel free to replace it with **auth()->user()**

Comment: Care to explain why `auth()->user();` would be a better syntax over the other one?

Comment: It does not give any advantage over Auth::user() other than being fluent. That's why I find (prefer) it better. Laravel is all about fluent syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

If `Auth:user()` is null, that means that the system didn't get an authenticated user.
But if you want to get the authenticated user you should to use `Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()` thats retrive the `User` model

Answer (score 1):

Check your route if you added the auth middleware and try using this code.

```
auth()->user();
```

and that will retreive the authenticated user same as `Auth::user();`